# how to create running text like <marquee> in facebook application?

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs, marquee

I need to show a running text scrolling from up to down, but fbml blocks `<marquee>`. Suggestions?

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
<div align="center"> <marquee bgcolor="#000080" scrollamount="2" 
direction="up" loop="true" width="35%"> <center> 
<font color="#ffffff" size="+1"><strong> THIS 
IS A COOL WAY<br> TO MAKE YOUR TEXT<br> SCROLL UPWARDS<br> <br> 
IT IS EASY AND FAST LOADING </strong></font> </center> </marquee></div>
```

Comment: marquee is sooooo deprecated!

Comment: link to support above statement: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a fan page, you can switch from using the deprecated fbml tabs to using the new iframe pages and then it should be allowed. If you need to use FBML, look for a javascript scrolling text script.

Comment: `<marquee/>` is a terrible idea though; way better to use one of the millions of javascript marquee/scroller scripts if you can.